# How to make sure the Dojo AMD loader gets a new (uncached) version

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd

At the moment we're aggregating our javascript files and putting a far future expiry on them, so returning users get the benefit of having the file cached. Then we change the filename when we have updates, so we know they'll get the new one.

How would that work with an AMD loader? (We're moving to Dojo, which is why I ask about that specifically). I know I could move everything into a new directory with a version number and modify the dojo config, but it feels like that means I'd have to say everything is updated, instead of just targeting the things that actually were.

I'd like it to happen as automatically as possible, of course. Seems like we might have to pass a version number from the build process or something, but I'm not seeing how the pieces come together yet.

Comment: You're probably better off deploying a built version of dojo. Otherwise you'll notice your users can be making 100s of requests for modules.

Comment: That's of course correct, but I don't expect dojo will be updating that often, so we'd be using a built version. However we'd have our own modules, separated into useful built files, and sometimes those files would be updated. I want to be sure the users get the updated ones and don't just keep the cached ones.